# 3-tier Architecture business logic

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a question about **Service Layer** - now my controllers interacts with Service Layer where I work with EF Context but sometime business logic inside Service methods can be really huge approximately 1000 lines.
For example:

```
class OrderService {

   public async Task UpdateOrder(OrderDto dto) {

      if(dto.Products.Count > 3)
      {
         **change order status that can take 300 lines**
      } 

   }
}
```

Where can I keep that logic that I use inside if statement ? 
Usually I just create private method inside that service but I'm not sure that it is a good approach. Maybe create specific class for that or something like this ?

Thank you.

Comment: May be add another layer for Business Logic? Service layer can talk to Business logic and business logic to Data layer.

Comment: @imAbhi thank u for suggestion, I already tried to find proofs that I can do it like you said, but I can't.
And how to use it then, not all my methods need 500 lines of business logic, or call it through business service always even if I don't need any specific logic ?

Comment: Maybe think about adding a OrderServiceHelper. You're class and methods should adhere to the Single Responsibility Principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

This ensures that your class is only doing one thing, and doing that thing well. The update order method can then call off to this class to perform the logic when a status changes.

Answer (score 2):

This question can go more to the developer's personal point of view. Here's some techniques I use to organize my code. Just try to see if they fit your scenario and change them to your need.

1. Move some logic to your entities.Example: An entity should be able to know if is in a good state.

> Entity.Type = Square
>
> Entity.Edges = 3
>
> Entity.IsValid() => False // Squares has 4 edges

2. You can create multiple classes that will help you add some logic to your code. In a feature/entity you can create multiple validation classes and then do something like `entity.AddValidation(EdgeValidator)`.
3. If you'll have a different algorithm base on conditions you can use the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) which is a [Behavioral patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_pattern).

> If House.FamilySize == 1 then ProcessAlgorithm = SinglePersonAlgorithm
>
> Else ProcessAlgorithm = MultiplePersonAlgorithm
>
> ProcessAlgorithm(House)

4. The old and classic split a function in multiple ones.

Comment: You can create multiple classes that will help you add some logic to your code.
But where can I keep these classes ?

Comment: @AlexKvitchastiy they are many answers for that. Basically it will depend of what class you're making and the context. If is a validator you can have a `validators` folder; Maybe is a helper inside `helpers`; Or maybe it is some kind of class that implements some behavior for your orders. If that the case i would put that class in special place where all of its kind will be. I think it would be in at the same level as the services  in the core project.

Comment: @AlexKvitchastiy Forgot to mention why yo should move logic to your entities. In an ideal world they are suppose to know what is the valid state of itself. If there is some some process to get some value base on an entity, it should be the responsible. Now if you have some business logic you throw that into a service so it knows how the business should work.

Answer (score 0):

Incapsulating different branches of `if` statements in separate classes may require some rework and refactoring but may well lead to great results and allow you to use patterns like for example

- Chain of responsibility
- Pipeline processing

and eventually all other [Behavioral patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_pattern)